# Disposable Camera Charging Circuit - Will it transfer a maximum amount of energy?

Tags: pcb, capacitor, camera, charging

This may sound naive but I would like to build a toy coil gun. I have seen designs where a charging circuit from a disposable camera is used to charge a capacitor. What if I wanted to use more battery power to charge up a bigger capacitor? Would I encounter problems? Would larger components ruin that type of cheaply priced circuit board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. Most likely. -- Note: it won't likely ruin the actual "circuit board", just some of the other components on it.

You should try it though. Could be a fun experiment.

Just make sure that you follow good electrical safety precautions. Depending on the circuit, the voltages can get quite high.